# elementwise outer product of tensors using einsum

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, numpy-einsum

I have the following two arrays:

```
foo = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

and

```
bar = np.array([k1, k2, k3])
```

where

```
k1 = np.array([[1],[2]])
k2 = np.array([[4],[6]])
k3 = np.array([[9],[3]])
```

I want to find the `elementwise outer product` of each third of `foo` and `bar`. In other words foo needs to be rearranged 
as follows before being fed into `np.outer`:

```
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

Here is what I have done.

```
def elmntwise_outer_prod(arr1, arr2):
    arr1 = np.split(arr1, 3)
    out = [np.outer(val1, val2) for val1, val2 in zip(arr1, arr2)]
    return np.array(out)
```

Now, when I do `elmntwise_outer_prod(foo, bar)` it gives me the desired output of

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
    [ 2,  4],
    [ 3,  6]],

   [[16, 24],
    [20, 30],
    [24, 36]],

   [[63, 21],
    [72, 24],
    [81, 27]]])
```

**Question** Is there a better way to do this?. In particular, how can I use `np.einsum` to write this more efficiently, if at all?. I have read the previous questions that address similar questions but I can't seem to get my head around this. I have also read [this](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) blog post RE `np.einsum`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no sum-reduction involved, so we can simply use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(foo.reshape(-1,3)[:,None,:]*bar).swapaxes(1,2)
# or foo.reshape(-1,3)[...,None]*bar[:,None,:,0]
```

If you have to use `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ij,ikl->ijk',foo.reshape(-1,3), bar)
```

Comment: maybe `.reshape(-1, 1, 3)` for `.reshape(-1, 3)[:, None, :]`?